# How to align popup editor with grid cell?

Tags: c#, winforms, propertygrid

I have a property grid with a custom editor using a `UITypeEditor`.
I want to align its popup window with the property grid's cell, like the default color editor when the property is a `Color`, but I can't find any information about the grid cell's location and size.

My `UITypeEditor.EditValue` method gets a `PropertyDescriptorGridEntry` object as the `context` parameter, but it also has no coordinates, and its `GridItems` collection is empty.

Ideas anybody? Are there (free) alternatives to PropertyGrid that offer this 
information?

Here is my current code:

```
class MyPropertyGridEditor : UITypeEditor
{
    public override UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle( System.ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext context )
    {
        return UITypeEditorEditStyle.Modal;
    }

    // Displays the UI for value selection.
    public override object EditValue( 
                      System.ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext context,
                      System.IServiceProvider provider,
                      object value )
    {
        var form = new MyEditorForm( true );
        // ??? Where can I find Location and Size of the grid cell ???
        if( form.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK )
        {
            value = form.Items;
        }

        return value;
    }
}
```

[image: Example of how my own editor shall be aligned]

The above is an example of how I want my form to be aligned, the example shows the default color editor.

Comment: The default behavior is keeping the alignment. I couldn't reproduce the problem which you've faced with. Consider posting a [MCVE].

Comment: Looks like [bike-shedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_triviality) to me . If you really want to adjust, how about using something like [DevExpress property grid](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraVerticalGrid.PropertyGridControl.class) and see in their sources how to hook into the popup creation process? Or how about looking at [the reference source of the original property grid](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/PropertyGrid.cs) to better understand and possibly hook-in?

Comment: I added sample code and clarified that the shcreenshot only shows an example of how my form should be aligned. There's nothing wrong with the alignment of the color editor, but I want my own editor to be shown that way.

Comment: @Uwe Klein: I want to open source my program, so commercial products are no option. As I stated above.

Comment: Have you tried to use UITypeEditorEditStyle.DropDown instead of Modal, and IWindowsFormsEditorService.DropDownControl instead of showing a Form? That's what the color editor does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behavior is keeping the alignment. As also mentioned in the other answer, you are showing a dialog rather than showing a drop down.

Here is an example to show a simple dropdown. You can show any control as dropdown, in this example, I've shown a `ListBox`:

```
public class MyComponent : Component
{
    [Editor(typeof(MyUITypeEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    public string SampleProperty { get; set; }
}

public class MyUITypeEditor : UITypeEditor
{
    public override UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return UITypeEditorEditStyle.DropDown;
    }
    IWindowsFormsEditorService svc;
    public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context,
        IServiceProvider provider, object value)
    {
        var list = new ListBox();
        var items = new[] { "A", "B", "C" };
        list.Items.AddRange(items);
        list.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.One;
        list.SelectedIndex = 0;
        if (items.Contains(($"{value}")))
            list.SelectedIndex = items.ToList().IndexOf($"{value}");
        list.SelectedValueChanged += List_SelectedValueChanged;
        svc = provider.GetService(typeof(IWindowsFormsEditorService))
            as IWindowsFormsEditorService;
        svc.DropDownControl(list);
        return list.SelectedItem;
    }

    private void List_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        svc.CloseDropDown();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all - you don't show popup, bud dialog. That's two different things.

The PropertyGrid component is prety complex and custom popup is not that easy as it looks.

There is source code with color editor, you can inspire from that.

http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/DotNET/DotNET/8@0/untmp/whidbey/REDBITS/ndp/fx/src/Designer/Drawing/System/Drawing/Design/ColorEditor@cs/1/ColorEditor@cs